# How to count the number of days that pass between two dates in a dataset column in R

Tags: r, date, group-by, count

I am working with a dataset [This is the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJY4m.jpg). In the dataset there are 33 unique Ids that are repeated for each day they provided data, within 30 days, from their fitbit. I am trying to count the number of days they input data through the ActivityDay column and group it to the Id, so that I can see how many total days they used their fitbit out of the 30 days.
the Activity date data type was originally POSIXct and I converted it to Date type. How can I count the dates as number or days and group it to each indvidual ID?

I tried using count within a dplyr::summarise to get the ID and number of days counted while grouping the data to the ID. that failed.
I also thought of using a case_when, however, I thought that wouldn't work because it wouldn't count all the way up to the end dates I specify, so anything between the two dates would get the ouputs I specified. I also tried count_date_between(min(user_device_activity), max(user_device_activity), by 'day') but it said that the function doesn't exist and when I tried installing it. It said it didn't exist within R.

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show the reproducible example instead of images

Comment: This is an example of `difftime` and there are many relevant examples on this web site.

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
user_device_activity %>%
  distinct(Id, ActivityDate) %>% # in case duplicates possible in data
  count(Id, month = lubridate::floor_date(ActivityDate, "month"))
```